# what and why is Origami(prototyping framework by facebook) used for?

Tags: css, facebook, photoshop

Hey guys just came across [this](https://facebook.github.io/origami/)(orgami by facebook) tool online here , seems to be something exciting , looks like some css3 transitions .

can somebody tell me what this tool is used for ? is it a kind of a replacement for psd kind of prototyping ?

can somebody give me a basic idea of what this tool really is and what it is used for ?

Answer (score 0):

Like you've said, it is a prototyping tool for designing rich interactable user interfaces.

Judging by some of the documentation it looks like they are trying to take on popular Mac (Quartz powered) application [Sketch](http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/)

Comment: is't sketch suppose to be a competitor for PSD ? i have never used sketch , but can you create css-3 like interactive designs with it ? just asking out of curiosity !

Comment: I believe designers use Sketch as part of a design tool chain (it does not support animation itself). So it seems as though Origami is offering an all in one solution.

Answer (score 0):

Origami is interface animation tool. It allows you to create animated UI from within the Quartz composer, or you could import your sketch file into origami and add animations to it.